# How to create a multilevel menu in Long Dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use this Menu called: Very Long Dropdown Menu. : [ [::: link :::](http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/) ]

The code for the menu is as follows:

BODY:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Really Tall Menu</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">No Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/

ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 8px;
    color: #222;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}
ul.dropdown li a:hover,
ul.dropdown li a.hover {
    background: #F3D673;
    position: relative;
}

/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/

ul.dropdown ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.dropdown ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #eee !important;
}
ul.dropdown ul li a:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #F3D673 !important;
}
```

Javascript / Jquery:

```
var maxHeight = 400;

$(function() {

    $(".dropdown > li").hover(function() {

        var $container = $(this),
            $list = $container.find("ul"),
            $anchor = $container.find("a"),
            height = $list.height() * 1.1, // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
            multiplier = height / maxHeight; // needs to move faster if list is taller

        // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
        $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

        // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
        $anchor.addClass("hover");

        // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
        $list
            .show()
            .css({
                paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
            });

        // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
        if (multiplier > 1) {
            $container
                .css({
                    height: maxHeight,
                    overflow: "hidden"
                })
                .mousemove(function(e) {
                    var offset = $container.offset();
                    var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                    if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                        $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                    };
                });
        }

    }, function() {

        var $el = $(this);

        // put things back to normal
        $el
            .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
            .find("ul")
            .css({
                top: 0
            })
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("a")
            .removeClass("hover");

    });

    // Add down arrow only to menu items with submenus
    $(".dropdown > li:has('ul')").each(function() {
        $(this).find("a:first").append("<img src='images/down-arrow.png' />");
    });

});
```

............................................................................

This is a scrollable menu, and is coded to auto-scroll as the user scrolls or brings the mouse hover down for viewing the contents of the sub menu.

I'm trying to add a submenu > subcategory to this menu. For example, while the menu is being scrolled, could there be a sub menu for each listed item in this menu? I only need three levels of submenus in total. Currently it's two including the top nav..: 
1. Top Nav (that's shown as default)
2. Submenu (That's shown when hovered upon top nav. (and is scrollable).
3. Subcategory (that should be shown when any menu item in "submenu" is hovered on or clicked on.

Is this possible for this plugin/script?

Here's what I tried to do, but couldn't achieve with my attempt..:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Really Tall Menu</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
             <li>
                 <a href="#">Submenu Artificial tarf</a>
                 <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">2 Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">7 Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">8 Padding</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">No Menu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also found this on codepen.io: http://codepen.io/larrygeams/pen/feoDc

Please could someone provide any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I asked the same question to a G+ user, and his script url is as follows: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kIHzu ... it's an altered version of the same script. My problem remains cause the submenus are overlapping each other in this version.

Comment: Hello!
did you find any solution? I need this improvement too.